# How to Get Notified When the Insertion Point Leaves a NSComboBox

Tags: macos, cocoa, combobox, swift3

I want to gain control when the insertion point leaves a combobox so that I can test if the text matches an entry in the combox's list. I've already added a delegate to my view controller for other combobox functions, for example:

```
func comboBox(_ aComboBox: NSComboBox, completedString string: String) -> String?
```

The following function looks like what I want:

```
func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool
```

My App Code IDE identifies it as being in the API. When I run my code, it doesn't get invoked (I have a print statement in it). I tried changing "control" to "comboBox" without success. Do I need to do something additional to get this function to be called?

## Update

As was pointed out by @Mangerlahn, the function needs to be in the datasource. I moved it there with no effect. It was in the delegate.

```
extension TrackDialogViewController: NSComboBoxDataSource {
...
func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {...}
...
}
```

Comment: The control.. function is part of the ´NSControlTextEditingDelegate´ and therefore part of the NSComboBoxDelegate methods. If you have set yourself as the delegate of the comboBox the method should be called. 

However, comboBox(..completedString..) is part of the NSComboBoxDataSource, which is different from the delegate. So make sure you are set as the comboBox' delegate AND datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid User Error. I lost a RAID drive and had to restart. XCode got messed up and was displaying two window for my project. The one I was looking at didn't have the console.